# Django query - field contains another

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I tried:

```
from django.db.models import F
MyObj.objects.filter(field1__contains=F('field2'))
```

It's empty, whilst the following indeed gives me results:

```
[o for o in MyObj.objects.all() if o.field1 and o.field2 in o.field1]
```

Here is the model definition:

```
class MyObj(models.Model):
     field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
     field2 = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CHOICES, default='a', db_index=True)
```

Isn't it possible to do that with `F` objects?

Comment: Check what is printed `print MyObj.objects.filter(field1__contains=F('field2')).query.__str__()`?

Comment: @alecxe: `SELECT ... FROM "myapp_myobj" where "myapp_myobj"."field1"::text LIKE "myapp_myobj"."field2"`

Comment: Hm, interesting. Please include `MyObj` model definition into the question. Thanks.